# Consider defining a bean of type 'com.gisapp.gisapp.dao.IUserDAO' in your configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

When I start my spring-boot app I have this message:

> APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Field userDAO in com.gisapp.services.impl.UserService required a bean
>   of type 'com.gisapp.gisapp.dao.IUserDAO' that could not be found.
>
> The injection point has the following annotations:
>     - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type 'com.gisapp.gisapp.dao.IUserDAO' in
>   your configuration.

What I have read in other post related to this problem is that I have to configure the annotation @ComponentScan, but it does not work

MAIN CLASS:

```
package com.gisapp.gisapp;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.gisapp")
public class GisappApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GisappApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

SERVICE CLASS

```
@Service
public class UserService implements IUserService {

    @Autowired
    IUserDAO userDAO;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public  Object login() {


        return userDAO.login();
    }

}
```

- UserDAO

```
package com.gisapp.gisapp.dao.impl;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import com.gisapp.gisapp.dao.IUserDAO;
import com.gisapp.models.entity.User;

public class UserDAO implements IUserDAO{

    @Override
    public Object login() {

        StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();

        query.append("SELECT * FROM User");

        EntityManager em = null;
        Query q = em.createNativeQuery(query.toString());

        List<User> result=q.getResultList();

        return result;

    }

}
```

IUserDAO should be recognised as a bean and the app should run

Comment: show the class that implements the IUserDAO .. with the package

Comment: I have edited the post in orther to show the IUserDAO implementation, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** Add a `@Repository` annotation in order for the DAO to be loaded as a bean into the spring context:

```
@Repository
public class UserDAO implements IUserDAO{
```

**2)** Just on the side.. you should most likely inject the `EntityManager` in it also:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
```